# How to get a document which is being identified by unique id numbers, but firebase auth provides only email on login?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a website where users can log in to their accounts and from there they can add money to their RFID tags, view their balance and transactions. The RFID tags are used for payment on places like vending machines.

The problem I am facing is that I have made the dashboard and have done all of the codings, any user can go on the dashboard and do all the above-specified things. I have also made a login page using firebase authentication which uses the email of the user to log them in.

I have a 'users' collection in my cloud firestore, which then has documents of users having document_id = the unique RFID number assigned to them.

Now, my question is that once a user logs in from the firebase authentication how do I get the document of the user who logged in because the documents are identified using the numbers and the users log in with their emails.

I have the user's emails inside a field in their individual documents.

What I am thinking is that is there any way so that I can assign the RFID number in the login activity, in the firebase project users? that way the RFID number can be fetched when the users login and hence their documents can be opened.

This is the only issue that's left in my project.

I have 4 files currently in my project.

```
Login.html
Login.js
Dashboard.html
Dashboard.js
```

My payments are handled by an external gateway which I implemented through their API.

Comment: Firebase Authentication automatically assigns a unique ID for each user.  You should be using that instead of email address.  Typically that is also used as the id of documents in Firestore for each user.

Comment: @DougStevenson In my project on the vending machine side when someone taps to pay using the RFID then the rfid number is used to get the data of the user and deduct the balance from his/her account. If I use any other kind of id then I would not be able to do the above specified process

Comment: You can store that RFID in the user's document, then query for that value.  You don't have to rely on a single document get() to find data.

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried using the where clause to get the document which has some specified email. but when I use the where query I get returned with a large object containing the data I want plus a lot of other data like metadata, time stamp etc. how to specifically get just the data?

Comment: A query returns a snapshot with all the matching documents, and all the fields in each document. There is no way to change that behavior.  It's probably not as big as you think.

Comment: I used this code-

`docRef2.where("Email", "==", em).get().then(snapshot => {

    
    snapshot.docs.forEach(document => {
     if (document.exists) {
       console.log(" "+Object.values(document)[2]);
       console.log(Object.values(document));

     } else {
       // Do Something Else
     }
    });
  });
`

Comment: To get this output-


`
Document(users/610679771947, SnapshotVersion(Timestamp(seconds=1555591369, nanoseconds=48594000)), {Balance:9, Email:adnanfarooqui123@gmail.com, FirstName:Adnan, LastName:Farooqui, Phone:8120664516, UserID:610679771947}, {hasLocalMutations: false}), {hasCommittedMutations: false})

`

Comment: @DougStevenson I just need 
`
{Balance:9, Email:adnanfarooqui123@gmail.com, FirstName:Adnan, LastName:Farooqui, Phone:8120664516, UserID:610679771947}
`

Comment: How can I extract that out, I am a beginner so I don't have much idea.